# change root user to vagrant user while booting vagrant [ $ vagrant up ]

Tags: linux, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I want to install/download some packages while booting the vagrant. I am providing my script.sh file into VagrantFile but all installation/Download is happening with sudo privilege, that i dont want to. so i am trying to change the user to 'vagrant' user (on booting time) but unable to get it.

Here the output, i am printing log while booting the vagrant ($ vagrant up)
[Here: Vagrant_Booting_Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPS7f.png)

below one is the VagrantFile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

#
# Vagrant Configuration
#
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.hostname = "Master-Node"

  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"

   #
   # Installation
   #
   config.vm.provision "IPFS", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "../Scripts/setupIPFS.sh"
   end

 end
```

please help to change 'root' user to 'vagrant' user while booting vagrant [ $ vagrant up ]

Comment: Can you add the content of your vagrant file to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the script as the `vagrant` user you need `privileged: false`.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "scripts/test.sh"
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Lupuleasa , this is worked on my vagrant. :D